# How to detect CTRL+V in javascript with Cyrillic layout?

Tags: jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

I detect `ctrl+v` in keydown event in such a way:

```
.keydown(function(e){
   if ( e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 86 ) {
      console.log ('ctrl+v!');
   }
});
```

it works fine, when my layout is latin (English). But when I switch my layout to Russian (cyrillic) - `ctrl+v` is executed (text is inserted) but jQuery detection doesn't work. (`e.keyCode = 0` of cyrillic symbols).

P.S. I need it in good order (for preformatting inserted text )

P.P.S. My task was accomplished without detection of pasting. (just listening on keyup event was enough for me), but the problem exist on my PC (Ubuntu, Fx6). keyCode of Cyrillic symbols is recognized as 0, and you can't detect shortcuts with latin letters (`ctrl+c`,`ctrl+v`, etc).

Comment: Would something like 'jQuery(document).bind('paste', function(e){ alert('pasting!') })' work? I'm not sure what you mean by 'in good order'.

Comment: Weird, your code works for me also with russian kb-layout. What environment you are working in?

Comment: @Dr.Molle, I'm using Ubuntu and Firefox 6.

Comment: @ipr101, yeap, I googled and found out `.bind('paste')`, tnx. (although I don't need it anymore). But if it needed to detect `ctrl+t` or `ctrl+n`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works fo me on ubuntu too(FF 5):

```
.keypress(function(e){
    if ( e.ctrlKey && (e.which == 86 || e.which==118) ) {
      console.log ('ctrl+v!');
   }
});
```

for ctrl+n use

```
 if ( e.ctrlKey && (e.which == 110 || e.which==78) )
```

and for ctrl+t:

```
if ( e.ctrlKey && (e.which == 84 || e.which==116) )
```

Comment: Yeap. to me it works only with .keypress and e.which (both latin and cyrillic). With keyup or e.keyCode works only with latin :( thanks

Comment: From the jQuery website - this might explain why one works while the other doesn't:

`Note that keydown and keyup provide a code indicating which key is pressed, while keypress indicates which character was entered. For example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by keydown and keyup, but as 97 by keypress. An uppercase "A" is reported as 65 by all events. Because of this distinction, when catching special keystrokes such as arrow keys, .keydown() or .keyup() is a better choice.`

[link](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)